# Delete TOP 1 in Sqlite in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an iOS App that sync's data from a web-service.  Every once in a while a record will get duplicated and I need to be able to clear the duplications up.

I can easily check for duplications by using the following SQL:

```
SELECT ZOrderGUID, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM ZPurchaseOrder 
WHERE ZManufacturerID=18
GROUP BY ZOrderGUID
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

I need to be able to use those results to delete just on of the dupes - it is just usually 2 records.

I have tried to run this SQL:

```
SELECT LIMIT 1 * FROM ZPurchaseorder WHERE ZManufacturerID=18 AND ZOrderGUID=
(SELECT ZOrderGUID
FROM ZPurchaseOrder 
WHERE ZManufacturerID=18
GROUP BY ZOrderGUID
HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

To isolate the first dupe I find but in testing it locks up the SQLite Database Browser app I am using to test my SQL scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the first record like this (the `LIMIT` comes at the end of the query):

```
SELECT *
FROM ZPurchaseorder
WHERE ZManufacturerID=18
  AND ZOrderGUID = (SELECT ZOrderGUID
                    FROM ZPurchaseOrder 
                    WHERE ZManufacturerID=18
                    GROUP BY ZOrderGUID
                    HAVING Count(*) > 1)
LIMIT 1
```